# How to get minimum from multiple date columns in linq?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have 3 date type column in a table and i want to get only one minimum date from all the columns using linq.

**Table:**
Collected   Staged     Processed
1/20/2017   2/19/2017  3/17/2016
4/21/2017   6/18/2014  12/15/2015

**Needed result: 6/18/2014**

Currently i am using following code:

```
var collectedDate = queryResults.Min(d => d.Collected);
var stagedDate = queryResults.Min(d => d.Staged);
var ProcessedDate = queryResults.Min(d => d.Processed);
```

And then comparing these all three and store the minimum date in another variable.
How can i do it in some other good way?

Comment: In general, it sounds like you want `queryResults.Min(d => Math.Min(d.Collected.Ticks, Math.Min(d.Staged.Ticks, d.Processed.Ticks))`. I am not sure if Entity Framework can translate `Math.Min` and `Ticks` access into proper SQL query, so I personally would use this method - it is readable and understandable. In terms of performance, if you have proper indices on your table, then these 3 queries would fire in a moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create `List` using `collectedDate,stagedDate,ProcessedDate` then apply `Linq` on it. Please check this.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public class Test
    {
        public DateTime Collected {get; set;}
        public DateTime Staged {get; set;}
        public DateTime Processed {get; set;}
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Test> queryResults = new List<Test>();

        queryResults.Add(new Test(){Collected=Convert.ToDateTime("1/20/2017"),Staged=Convert.ToDateTime("2/19/2017"),Processed=Convert.ToDateTime("3/17/2016")});
        queryResults.Add(new Test(){Collected=Convert.ToDateTime("4/21/2017"),Staged=Convert.ToDateTime("6/18/2014"),Processed=Convert.ToDateTime("12/15/2015")});

        var collectedDate = queryResults.Min(d => d.Collected);
        var stagedDate = queryResults.Min(d => d.Staged);
        var ProcessedDate = queryResults.Min(d => d.Processed);

        List<DateTime> listDate = new List<DateTime>(){collectedDate,stagedDate,ProcessedDate};

        Console.WriteLine(listDate.Min(d => d));

        //2nd Solution
        //Compare DateTime between column and then rows to get min value
        Console.WriteLine(queryResults.Min(d => getMin(getMin(d.Collected, d.Staged), d.Processed)));
    }

    //Function to compare two DateTime
    public static DateTime getMin(DateTime a, DateTime b)
    {
        return a < b ? a : b;
    }
}
```

You can check output of the code in [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dcb8nE).

Answer (score 3):

As you working with database, it will be better to make one query instead of three:

```
var answer = (from item in queryResults
              group item by 0 into sub
              select new
              {
                  min1 = sub.Min(x => x.Collected),
                  min2 = sub.Min(x => x.Staged),
                  min3 = sub.Min(x => x.Processed)
              }).ToList().Select(x => new[] { x.min1, x.min2, x.min3 }.Min()).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: ToList() will make it IEnumerable instead of IQueryable, Everything after ToList will be in local memory. Can the following method be used?
Use IQueryable.Concat to concat the three lists of dates and then IQueryable.Min.

Comment: I not see any problems. Query will return three values from database and then will sort them in memory. On `Concat` you mean `Union All`, but it is not very good in terms of perfomance.

Comment: Why the `item => 0` (item by 0 into sub) ?

Comment: @GONeale, `group item by 0 into sub` it is a fake GroupBy, which needed to allow  syntax like: select several `.Min(x => x.Collected), .Min(x => x.Staged) ...`. You can group by any value: 0, true, 33.